# Backbone View Events are not Firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a modal dialog class that I am extending in order to show a form with some buttons. Here is the ModalView view:

```
App.ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .dismiss": "dismiss"
    },
    element: "<section class='modal'><div class='overlay'></div><div class='content'></div></section>",

    initialize: function () {
        this.el = $(this.element);

        this.setupElement();
        this.bindContext();
        this.extendEvents();
        this.render();
        this.miscellaneous();
    },

    bindContext: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "dismiss", "render", "setBoxStyle");
    },

    setupElement: function () {
        this.template = $("#modal-template");
    },

    miscellaneous: function () {},
    extendEvents: function () {},

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).find(".content").html(this.template.html());
        $("body").append(this.el);

        this.setBoxStyle();

        if (this.options.content) {
            $(this.el).find(".content").html(this.options.content);
        }
    },

    getMargin: function (width, height) {
        var top, left;

        width = parseFloat(width);
        height = parseFloat(height);

        top = Math.max(0, Math.round((window.innerHeight - height) / 2));
        left = Math.max(0, Math.round((window.innerWidth - width) / 2));

        return top + "px " + left + "px";
    },

    setBoxStyle: function () {
        var css = this.options.css || {};

        var el = $(this.el).find(".content");

        el.css(css);

        var width = el.outerWidth();
        var height = el.outerHeight();
        css.margin = this.getMargin(width, height);

        el.css(css);
    },

    dismiss: function () {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the extended view:

```
App.AddRecordView = App.ModalView.extend({
    setupElement: function () {
        this.template = $("#add-record-template");
    }
});
```

Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="add-record-template">
    <h1>Add Record</h1>

    <button class="green save">Save Record</button>
    <button class="cancel dismiss">Cancel</button>

</script>
```

Here is how I initialize the view:

```
this.addRecordView = new App.views.addRecord({
    model: this.model,
    css: {
        width: "400px"
    }
});
```

For some reason the dismiss event never fires when I click the button. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not defined an el or a tagName for your view. Backbone assigns the delegate events to a div by default if none of the above are declared. In your initialize function you then set the el explicitly, overriding the el with the eventhandlers attached. Try to set your section as tagName and remove it from your element property.  Then append your elements to this.el. 
Sorry for not providing a code example but I am writing on my phone.

Comment: That's a great idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: This was one of 2 problems. Here is problem number 2: Backbone events do not inherit from one view to another when extended (http://goo.gl/UmdnF). If you want to replicate the events of super, you have to either declare the events in duplicate on the child view, or declare the events attribute to be a function that returns an events hash, then call super on the child element. E.g. App.AddRecordView.events = function () { return $.extend(App.ModalView.prototype.events.call(this), { "click .save": "saveRecord" }); } and App.ModalView.events = function () { return { "click .dismiss": "dismiss" }

Answer (score 0):

without the proper code i can only guess,
but this kind of error usually comes because your view's code is declared before the dom is ready.

could you show us where you kickstart your application?

is it within a jquery document ready function?

```
$(function(){
    this.addRecordView = new App.views.addRecord({
        model: this.model,
        css: {
            width: "400px"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's created by a method of another view, which is triggered by a click event on a button, so I know that the DOM is ready.

Comment: alright, sorry for my quick assumption, i just came across this issue several times before and it was the above solution fixing it every time.
i'll take a look at it tomorrow and see if i can find a solution